# How to add 1 for the last week of a month and bfill as 0 in pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the below dataframe and I need to fill 1 for last week of that month and year and rest weeks for the same month and year as 0

df:

```
date        total
02/01/00    28.000568
09/01/00    28.000568
16/01/00    28.000568
23/01/00    28.000568
30/01/00    28.000568
06/02/00    12.500612
13/02/00    12.500612
```

output:

```
date        total         flg
02/01/00    28.000568     0
09/01/00    28.000568     0
16/01/00    28.000568     0
23/01/00    28.000568     0
30/01/00    28.000568     1
06/02/00    12.500612     0
13/02/00    12.500612     0
```

please could you advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to `datetime`, then find where the month changes row to row:

```
d = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],dayfirst=True).dt.month

df['flag'] = d.ne(d.shift(-1)).astype(int)

>>> df
       date      total  flag
0  02/01/00  28.000568     0
1  09/01/00  28.000568     0
2  16/01/00  28.000568     0
3  23/01/00  28.000568     0
4  30/01/00  28.000568     1
5  06/02/00  12.500612     0
6  13/02/00  12.500612     1
```

Note that I did this separately, so as to not change your `date` format in your dataframe. You could also do it in place:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'],dayfirst=True)

df['flag'] = df['date'].dt.month.ne(df['date'].dt.month.shift(-1)).astype(int)
```

Also note that the last row is flagged, even though that's not in your desired output. Technically, that is the last entry for month 2